# Trying to set ng-class of AngularJS accordion-heading does nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an accordion where some of the entries need to have a heading that emphasizes that the data in that group shows a problem that needs attention.  I tried using a "accordion-heading" with a "ng-class" for "has-error" (from bootstrap) that is conditional on the method that determines whether there is something that needs attention.  I've tried several variations of this, and the "class" attribute never gets rendered in the HTML.

This is an excerpt from my HTML:

```
        <accordion close-others="false">
            <div ng-repeat="(name, dataSource) in dataSourceMap">
                <accordion-group>
                    <accordion-heading>
                        <span ng-class="{'has-error': anyFailuresInList(dataSource)}">
                            {{name}}
                        </span>
                    </accordion-heading>
                    {{anyFailuresInList(dataSource)}}
                </accordion-group>
            </div>
        </accordion>
```

The example in the documentation at [enter link description here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) indicates that this should be possible, even though the example is a little broken (it appears to put the class on an empty "i" element).

Comment: You syntax looks to be correct. Try to recreate your situation in the Plunkr [example for the Accordion directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) on the UI-Bootstrap site.

Comment: The empty "i" element in the example is the expand/collapse icon at the end of the line. Perhaps your `anyFailuresInList(dataSource)` call isn't producing the value you're expecting, which is why the class isn't getting applied. Try inspecting the scope or displaying the result of the call (with `<span>{{anyFailuresInList(dataSource) | json}}</span>` or something) to get more information.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it actually was applying the class, it was just deeper in the tree than I expected.  There's also something wrong with my CSS, or what I expected from the bootstrap CSS, as applying that class didn't give me the styling I expected.  That's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

`accordion-group` doesn't support `ng-class` well.
Please use class instead.
If you want to set the style conditionally, you can use the `?` operator. For instance:

```
<uib-accordion-group class="{{isSpecial ? 'special-style':''}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by applying a css class to the group instead of the header directly

```
    <div accordion-group is-open="node.active" is-disabled="node.active" ng-class="{'panel-active': node.active}" ng-repeat="(key,node) in nav.nodes">
         <div accordion-heading >{{node.title}}</div>  
    </div>
```

Then in your css change the back for the first DIV

```
.panel-active>div {
   background-color: #YourActiveColor;
   border-color: #YourActiveColor;
}
```